# InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo: how do I know the interface ID?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I want to use InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo to check if a COM object supports IErrorInfo. I can't figure out where do I get the riid parameter from.

I get the CComPtr in the follwing way:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
CComPtr<IDispatch> pCOM;
pCOM.CoCreateInstance(L"<ClassName>", NULL, CLSCTX_ALL);
```

Then I get a failed HRESULT from pCOM->InvokeN call. 
I know the object supports IErrorInfo because GetErrorInfo returns it successfully, but I'd like to know how to formally check if the interface is supported.

I tried

```
CComQIPtr<ISupportErrorInfo, &IID_ISupportErrorInfo> pSupportErrorInfo(pCOM);
pSupportErrorInfo->InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo(IID_IDispatch);
```

but it returns S_FALSE.

Comment: It doesn't apply to late-bound calls through IDispatch::Invoke().  The same info you'd get through IErrorInfo is returned through the EXCEPINFO argument you pass to Invoke().

Comment: You have to know the IID ahead of time, you can't query for it dynamically. You have to use the IID of the interface that you used to make the call that failed. You are creating the object as an `IDispatch`, so the IID is `IID_Dispatch`, but if that doesn't work for `InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo()` then there is nothing you can do. Why are you using `IDispatch`at all  instead of using `ISomeDerivedInterface`?

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, the EXCEPINFO really works. I don't get why Microsoft didn't leverage it in CComPtr::InvokeN method.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's a pity. I wanted to use IDispatch for late binding.

Comment: `InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo` would probably return true for IDispatch-descendant but not IDispatch itself. So as said about you have to know the `iid`. Or quite so often you it's the identifier you can obtain via `IProvideClassInfo`.

Comment: @AlexVB But why do you want to use late binding in a strictly typed language, like C++?  Late binding is necessary for dynamic languages like scripting environments, but it is rarely desirable for environments that can use early/static binding instead, like C++

Comment: @RemyLebeau AFAIK, early binding may fail if library version on user system is incompatible with that on development system. I had once an issue with a program that used early binding to Excel. It was some bug in ms office setup in a user system, but I couldn't fix it and had to switch to late binding.

Comment: @AlexVB COM interfaces are not allowed to be changed between library versions, for exactly the reason of compatibility. You are coding to a specific interface, not to a specific library version. As long as the COM author follows the rules (and MS does, since they set the rules), you shouldn't have a problem with using early/static binding with multiple/dev-release library versions.